# How to automate spring boot docker commands

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

How to build one Gradle task that clean and build springBoot jar then build and run the command of docker-compose up in order to automate/combine the steps and commands in one call for having up and running docker image of spring boot application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this plugin to your Gradle project:

https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin

2. Set up the Docker Compose plugin:

```
dockerCompose {
    forceRecreate = true
}
```

3. Make the `composeUp` task depend on `clean` and `bootJar`:

```
tasks.composeUp.dependsOn('clean', 'bootJar')
```

4. Create your `Dockerfile` that will build your image using the JAR output from the `bootJar` task
5. Create your Docker Compose file, and include an entry that will build your image:

```
services:
  spring-boot-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

6. `./gradlew composeUp`